# Project Euler JavaScript #2 Can't figure out how to print the total

Tags: javascript, fibonacci

If I put this in to codeacademy labs, it returns the sum. But I can't figure out why it won't print/log/return the total when I tell it to.

```
var a = 0,
 b = 1,
 f = 1,
 fibNums = [];
 sum = 0;


while (f < 4000000) {
    f = a + b;
    if ( f > 4000000 ) {
        break;
    } else {
        a = b;
        b = f;
        fibNums.push(f);
        i ++;
    }
}

for (i =0; i < fibNums.length; i++) {
    if (fibNums % 2 === 0) {
        sum += fibNums(i);
    }
}
```

Comment: how are you trying to print/log/return the total?

Comment: There is one error in `while` loop `i ++` won't have a space between `i` and `++`. Please explain what is it that you want to print/log/return?

Answer (score 1):

You have several errors in your code.

You need to access array elements using `[]` and not `()`. In your case sum is always `0` since you are accessing array in wrong way.

Here is the working code:

```js
var a = 0,
  b = 1,
  f = 1,
  fibNums = [];
sum = 0;


while (f < 4000000) {
  f = a + b;
  if (f > 4000000) {
    break;
  } else {
    a = b;
    b = f;
    fibNums.push(f);
   
  }
}

for (var i = 0; i < fibNums.length; i++) {
  if (fibNums[i] % 2 == 0) {   // access array elements using [] notation
    sum += fibNums[i]; // access array using []
  }
}

console.log(sum); // Log the sum
console.log(fibNums); //log the fibNums array
```

Comment: please explain the changes you made and why you made them

Comment: @AndrewL: Please point out error if any so that I can correct it

Comment: There is no need to use `if else` inside while, as the `while` statement will check the condition itself. Also this line is useless `i++` as there is no `i` inside the `while`. `while (f < 4000000) {
  f = a + b;
  a = b;
  b = f;
  fibNums.push(f);
}`